# XAMPP Page Not Found, but Index.php works

Tags: php, xampp

Just installed XAMPP, and created a working webpage with index.php. I've added a second page, register.php, but I get the following error:

````
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.```
````

Based on other posts, this is typically just a typo or something, but here's my **"social" folder**:
[image: file tree]

My root page, index, works fine, but register doesn't work. I've tried the following urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/social/register
http://localhost:8080/social/register/
http://localhost:8080/social/register.php
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Does ``http://localhost:8080/social/index.php`` work or only ``http://localhost:8080/social``?

Comment: both of those links work

Comment: Are you sure of the extension? i.e., sometimes it may be register.php.txt but the os is hiding the later. Make sure of that by checking the file's properties.

Comment: Another way is to try and require this file in index.php and check if any error occurs. If so, you miscreated the file

Comment: Tried making a new file and it worked. Then I deleted my register.php and renamed the new file.